# How to execute batch operations like renaming and dropping on many T-sql tables?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have lots of tables stored in SSMS v.18.12.1 with similar names. I want to execute batch operations for all of them using a script. For example I want to rename column 'TracingNo' to 'tracing_no' for all table names starting with 'master_monthly_hist_'. I tried following script which gets list of similar table names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  and rename their columns, but it does not change the column name:
besides I want to drop all tables with names starting with 'master_monthly_hist_' which does not have column name 'Symbol' too.

```
 `Declare @SQL4 varchar(max) ='' Select @SQL4 = @SQL4 +'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N''{TracingNo}'' AND Object_ID = Object_ID( [sqlDB].[dbo].{'+TABLE_NAME+'}))  BEGIN exec sp_rename '' [sqlDB].[dbo].{'+TABLE_NAME+'}.{TracingNo}, {tracing_no} END From [sqlDB].[dbo].'+TABLE_NAME+' '   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'master_monthly_hist_%' and COLUMN_NAME like 'TracingNo'    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME set @SQL4='' Exec(@SQL4)`
```

second script:

```
'DECLARE cmds CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'drop table [' + Table_Name + ']'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE Table_Name in (select distinct TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'master_monthly_hist_%' 
  AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN (
                    select distinct TABLE_NAME
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                      WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'master_monthly_hist_%' AND COLUMN_NAME='Symbol')

OPEN cmds
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH cmds INTO @cmd
    IF @@fetch_status != 0 BREAK
    EXEC(@cmd)
END
CLOSE cmds;
DEALLOCATE cmds
```

Comment: *"I have lots of tables stored in SSMS v.18.12.1"* You don't store tables in SSMS; SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) is a GUI IDE-like application. Your tables are stored in a database, most likely hosted in a SQL Server instance.

Comment: Yes, you are true, I think the database is odbc. do you mean that by SSMS I can connect to other databases?

Comment: ODBC is a driver, not a database engine.

Comment: by default I connect to 'Master database'  with name 'master' but later I created 'sqlDB' for my works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this query:

```
DECLARE @SQL4 VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @SQL4 = @SQL4 +
    'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(''[sqlDB].[dbo].' + TABLE_NAME + ''')) BEGIN ' +
    'EXEC sp_rename ''[sqlDB].[dbo].' + TABLE_NAME + '.' + COLUMN_NAME + ''', ''tracing_no'' END;'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'master_monthly_hist_%' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'TracingNo'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

EXEC (@SQL4)
```

**Second Script Modified.**

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE cmds CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'DROP TABLE [' + Table_Name + ']'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE Table_Name LIKE 'master_monthly_hist_%'
AND Table_Name NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'master_monthly_hist_%' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Symbol'
)

OPEN cmds
FETCH NEXT FROM cmds INTO @cmd

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC(@cmd)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cmds INTO @cmd
END

CLOSE cmds
DEALLOCATE cmds
```

Comment: Using the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your data in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.

Comment: this script works ,would you give the script for the second problem of dropping tables too.

Comment: please share your script i will check and modify that script and send it to you

Comment: I added second script which drops tables with a condition. the selected tables are all similar tables excluding those without colum_name 'LetterCode'

Comment: i have shared please check